# possible to animate HorizontalAlignment in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I'd like to animate the horizontal (and vertical) alignment of an element within a `Grid`. I'd also like the animation to be continuous (not discrete left, center, and right values).

```
<!-- starting state -->
<Grid>
  <Button 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Content="Test"/>
  </Button>
</Grid>

<!-- ending state -->
<Grid>
  <Button 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Content="Test"/>
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

How do I accomplish this? There doesn't seem to be any animation type that supports this. Obviously this would be ideal:

```
<AlignmentAnimation From="Left" To="Right" />
```

Ideas?

Comment: Obviously the alignment enumeration doesn't have a continuous set of values. Your best bet would be to replace the containing `Grid` with a `Canvas` and animate the Button's horizontal position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate that property since it is just an `enum`. It would need intermediate values to have for the animation to work, [like double, Point, Color, Thickness, Size, etc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx).

Comment: No one said the animation had to be linear... it can have discrete keyframes

Comment: I've edited my question to require a linear/continuous animation.